# Можно ли открывать автоматически файл на сервере

Tags: python, ubuntu

такой вопрос есть выделенный сервер с Ubuntu, там включен питон файл иногда данный файл закрывается, можно ли как то автоматизировать ? Если закрывается этот файл то сервер сразу его опять включает и так по кругу. Спасибо за ранее )

Comment: `включен питон файл` значит, что он запущен как service / daemon ?

Comment: Запущен командой python3 main.py , что значит запущен как service / daemon?

Comment: значит что он запущен в качестве фонового процесса

Comment: Так его можно как то не вручную перезапускать ?

Comment: Можете создать сервис `systemd`

Comment: да @Mistorbballer , я как раз вел к тому, что выше написал nomnoms12

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете запустить свой скрипт в качестве сервиса [systemd](https://systemd.io/). Для этого нужно создать файл с расширением `service` в директории `/ets/systemd/system`.

***Пример сервиса:***

```
[Unit]
Description=Main
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=python main.py
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

При первом запуске не забудьте перезагрузить демон и активировать новый сервис:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable main.service
sudo systemctl start main.service
```

Comment: Он будет запускать файл если перезапустить сервер ? Или когда файл закрывается сервис его обратно открывает ?

Comment: @Mistorbballer, да он будет запускаться самостоятельно

Comment: @Mistorbballer Да, сервис будет запускаться после перезагрузки сервера. И будет автоматически перезапускаться в случае сбоев

Comment: @Mistorbballer Но есть нюансы. Из вашего вопроса совсем непонятно, что за скрипт вы запускаете, создаёт ли он дочерние процессы, с каким кодом завершается и т.д. Я бы советовал вам обратиться к официальной документации за подробностями работы systemd

Comment: Запускаю бота в Телеграмме